# Find Text and replace specific elements and format them

Tags: string, replace, format

I have seen a website, where you could with specific code, find certain elements in a text, for example:

```
5320  Agedrup
```

Here i could select, first element `5320`, and tell it to format it like this `(5320)`, and and a '`,`' instead of the two spaces, and the last element add another set of `()`.

so i would look like this:

```
(5320),(Agedrup)
```

It Can be used for selecting hundreds of theses lines, and formatting at the same time, there by saving time.

I have no idea if it is an official coding language, or which website it is...
Hope there is someone that knows what i am talking about..

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Toto That is what i can't remember, it was a couple of months since i used it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it was RegExr.com, 
with regex, i can select and replace and format it.

did it with:

```
two spaces first, to match the space between postalnumber and cityname replaced with ,"
then \n to find the start and end of line and replace with "),(
```

there by creating (5330, "munkebo") ready for sql.